# Url filtering in Django Rest Framework

Tags: jquery, django, url, django-rest-framework

I created a Django Rest Framework API endpoint.

Here is the view i created for my api endpoint:

```
class myApiList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = tst.objects.using.all()
    serializer_class = mySerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ('Status',)
```

This code lets me add filters when retrieving data from the API endpoint using Jquery on a standard webpage.

So, if on my page i want to show only the records with the status `Free` i will retrieve this endpoint:

```
("/myApi/?Status=Free")
```

But what if i want to show not only the items with the status `Free`, **but also** those with the status `Pending`?

I tried this, but it's not working, as it will only show the records with the status `Pending`

```
("/myApi/?Status=Free&Status=Pending")
```

Is there a way to solve this? Should i change something in the URL or do i have to make some changes from my Django Backend?

Comment: The *querystring* is not part of the path. You thus can not add that to the `url(..)`/`path(..)`

Comment: So there is no way to accomplish what i'm trying to do with DRF? @WillemVanOnsem